# About GNOME .gconf, .gnome2 etc. directories in $HOME

Tags: gnome, settings

In users $HOME we know that GNOME keeps various of directories to store user specific configs.

I know that `.gconf` is used to store user preferences (keybindings, and other settings)

I know that `.config` is used to store application specific preferences

Do you know what `.gnome2` and `.gnome2_private` `.gconf.path.defaults` and files`.gconf.path.mandatory`  `.gconf.xml.defaults` `.gconf.xml.mandatory`
for?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**.gnome2/** contains configuration files for applications, much like **.config/**. However **.config/** is standards compatible ([FreeDesktop](http://standards.freedesktop.org/basedir-spec/basedir-spec-latest.html)). While **.gnome2/** exists to be used by the now depreciated [gnome-config](http://developer.gnome.org/libgnome/stable/libgnome-gnome-config.html#libgnome-gnome-config.description). **.gnome2_private/** is like **.gnome2/**, but for configuration files that need to be private.

**gconf.xml.mandatory** and **gconf.xml.defaults** are XML for desktop settings like your local **.gconf**. gconf uses all three to configure the desktop. **.mandatory** can not be edited by a normal user, making it useful for kiosks and public-use computers, while **.defaults** is the base from which all default desktop settings are read.

In order of priority, **.mandatory** comes above (your local) **.gconf**, which in turn comes above **.defaults**. If a key is set in **.mandatory**, the same key in **.gconf** and **.defaults** will be ignored. Likewise, a key not set in **.mandatory** but set in **.gconf**, will override the same key in **.defaults**.

This is also the case for **.path.mandatory** and **.path.defaults** - except they are used to set the location of configuration sources, rather than describing the configuration itself.

Comment: Is this still the case in 2017?